# yii2 extract messages to db

Tags: php, yii2, internationalization

I'm using trntv/Yii2-starter-kit. How can I extract messages to DB?
My config:

```
'*'=> [
    'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
    'sourceMessageTable'=>'{{%i18n_source_message}}',
    'messageTable'=>'{{%i18n_message}}',
    'enableCaching' => YII_ENV_DEV,
    'cachingDuration' => 3600,
    'on missingTranslation' => ['\backend\modules\i18n\Module', 'missingTranslation']
]
```

My I18N file:

```
'sourcePath'=>Yii::getAlias('@base'),
'languages' => ['uz','ru'],
'translator' => 'Yii::t',
'sort' => false,
'removeUnused' => true,
'only' => [
    '*.php',
],
'ignoreCategories' => ['yii'],
```

I tryed:

```
php yii message @common/config/messages/_base.php
```

And
php yii message
But always it writes all messages to files: vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages. How can I export messages to DB? Has anyone help?

Comment: added an answer for you see if it helps you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following as per [**`CONSOLE-DOCS`**](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/console.md) there is a `ExtendedMessageControler` class. This controller extends default `MessageController` to provide some useful actions:

- To migrate messages between different message sources run the common like below

  **`php console/yii message/migrate @common/config/messages/php.php @common/config/messages/db.php`**

Which means you should have a file inside the `@common/confiog/messages/` folder with the name **`db.php`** that will be used to create the `message` and `source_message` tables the contents of the file should be

```
<?php
return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/_base.php'),
    [
        // 'db' output format is for saving messages to database.
        'format' => 'db',
        // Connection component to use. Optional.
        'db' => 'db',
        // Custom source message table. Optional.
        'sourceMessageTable' => '{{%i18n_source_message}}',
        // Custom name for translation message table. Optional.
        'messageTable' => '{{%i18n_message}}',
    ]
);
```

and the messages source directory will be determined by the **`php.php`** file inside the **`@common/config/messages`** directory that contains the following

```
<?php
return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/_base.php'),
    [
        // 'php' output format is for saving messages to php files.
        'format' => 'php',
        // Root directory containing message translations.
        'messagePath' => Yii::getAlias('@common/messages'),
        // boolean, whether the message file should be overwritten with the merged messages
        'overwrite' => true,
    ]
);
```

You just need to run the migration command and the tables will be created and the messages will be exported to the respective tables.

for more details see the [**`SOURCE`**](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/blob/master/console/controllers/ExtendedMessageController.php) for the `actionMigrate()`.